# Adding spaces between characters in string C++

Tags: c++, performance, c++11

I am looking for the most efficient way to add a space `" "` between every character in the string in C++.

So let's say I pass a string `"123"` and I want to get `"1 2 3 "` or `"1 2 3"` (it doesn't really matter).

Does anyone know the fastest way of doing such a thing?

My method so far looks like this...

```
    string output;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        output += s.substr(i, 1) + " ";
    }
    return output;
```

...but I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do it

Thanks

Comment: do you know a slow way of doing it? Please show it then maybe we can convince you that it is fast enough (or show you how to make it faster)

Comment: Do you want to create a new string, or simply to print it?

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the method I'm using now. I want to generate them and store them in the vector - not to print them out

Comment: Showing the code helps, but what do you mean by "efficient"? I've shown how to do it conveniently, but if this is a performance question, you need to provide a lot more information about the benchmarks you've run, and why you think your solution can be improved.

Comment: Note that in the same spirit you can use `output += s[i] + ' ';` Thanks to compiler optimisation, about all such methods should provide same efficiency. You can also use a `for range` loop.

Comment: @cigien I have multiple strings of numbers and I have to split each number with a space. It's just one of the steps I do in my code towards achieving my final goal. My code will be graded on efficiency therefore I'm trying to improve it in all possible ways - therefore the question asked (to see if there is a faster way)

Comment: Can you please check with your professor, or whoever is grading your code, what they mean by "code will be graded on efficiency"? Are they measuring run-time?

Comment: Yes - the runtime

Comment: you should ask them to provide you the details of their benchmarking technique. Otherwise their grading is pointless. You cannot optimize for constraints if you don't know the constraints

Comment: next you should profile your code to see if this part is a bottleneck. Only if some large fraction of the total runtime is spend in this code it is worth spending time in making this part faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write this conveniently with the range-v3 library. So given:

```
namespace rs = ranges;
namespace rv = ranges::views;

std::string input = "123";
```

If you just want to print the string with interspersed spaces, you can do:

```
rs::copy(input | rv::intersperse(' '), 
         rs::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
```

And if you want to store the result in a new string, you can do:

```
auto result = input | rv::intersperse(' ') | rs::to<std::string>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zhMe41).

I think this is about as efficient as it can reasonably get, but more importantly, it's very readable.

Comment: or the often laughed at "don't do it at all". Often its forgotten that the fastest way to do something is to not do it. If the added spaces are only supposed to appear on the screen when the string is printed, there is no need to allocate a string of twice the size of the original. Or writing an iterator that derefences to a `" "` every second time is also not too difficult.

Comment: @idclev463035818 True, added that option as well, thanks.

Comment: range-v3 claims to support C++14/17/20, OP tagged C++11.  But it looks really cool! 
 Is this what we're getting in C++20, or is range-v3 even more mature than what is going into C++20?  Reminds me a little of C# LINQ (and C# LINQ reminds me of F#).

Comment: @Eljay Ah, good point, I didn't see the C++11 tag. That's true, range-v3 needs at least C++14 to compile, (at least for the components in the demo). C++20 ranges is inspired heavily by range-v3, but it only has a small subset of it. We'll get more things in C++23, and even more after that :)

Answer (score 0):

The inefficiency of your code is repeated re-allocation of the string.

You know upfront the size of the `output`, so you should allocated that, filled with spaces. Then you simply place all character in their new position:

```
std::string foo(const std::string& s) {
  std::string output(s.length()*2-1, ' ');
  for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); ++i, j+=2) {
    output[j] = s[i];
  }
  return output;
}
```